# Print up to a word, replace that word, then print the rest of string (C)

Tags: c, loops, substring

Im having a lot of trouble printing up to the string and then replacing the word and then printing the rest of the string. I want to replace the "word" variable with \e[7m word \e[0m. I tried using strcasestr to get to to where word is in the string, and it returns a pointer starting at the string. My question is how do I use this pointer to print the string up to that point, replace the word with \e[7m word \e[0m, then print the rest of the string

```
        struct node *ptr;
int count = 0;
char* filecheck = "";
char* tester = "";
char* pch = "";
char str[1024];
int i; 
int j;
int charcount = 0;   

                int counter = 1;
                FILE *fp = fopen(ptr->fileName, "r");
                char line [ 1024 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
                int counter = 1;
                while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, fp ) != NULL ) /* read a line */{
                    //print the line
                     printf("\e[7m %s \e[0m", word);
                     printf("%s", line);

}
```

Comment: "loops"?  What loops?

Comment: You initialize `tester`, then replace that value with `line`, but never show us what `line` is.

Comment: The implementation in my code is a loop, but I thought itd be easier for people to do this without the loop so I took it out

Comment: line is a fgets line from a file, for easier purposes just assume tester is tester, I will delete tester= line

Comment: Then why did you leave the tag for it? You've reduced your code to the point that it's meaningless. If you have a question about why your code doesn't do something (or why it's doing something wrong), *post your actual code*. Otherwise, you're wasting both your time and ours.

Comment: I have added the full code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple way to do it

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *tester = "Hello my name is Rocky the polar bear";
    char *pch    = NULL;
    char *word   = "the";

    pch = strcasestr(tester, word);
    if (pch != NULL)
    {
        size_t length;

        /* this will give the difference between the pointers */
        length = pch - tester;
        /* write to stdout from the start of the string just 'length' bytes */
        fwrite(tester, 1, length, stdout);
        /* write the word you want to substitute */
        printf("\033[7m%s\033[0m", word);
        /* pch is pointing to the start of 'word' in the string, advance to it's end */
        pch += strlen(word);
        /* print the rest of the string */ 
        printf("%s", pch);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: mine returns a bunch of unicode, I cant get it to return start to the word, I can get everything else working though

Answer (score 1):

Printing the part after `word` is easy: just start at the character `strlen(word)` characters after where `word` starts.  Printing the replacement is trivial (unless you need to *compute* the replacement, which you've said nothing about how to do).

That leaves the part before `word`.  If `tester` didn't have a string constant in it, you could set `*pch` to 0, terminating the string at the start of `word`, and just print `tester` (then put the character you erased back).  Instead, you could copy the part of `tester` to be printed into a character array, and print that.